# Confused creating a HTML divs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a code where in there is a json given and out of the key value pairs of json I need to create HTML divs.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="col-md-12">

</div>

<input type="button" onclick="addDivs()" />
```

and my JS

```
        function addDivs() {
          var jsonInput = {
            'a': '1',
            'b': '2'
          }
          var colDiv = document.getElementById("col-md-12");
          var row = document.createElement("div");
          row.className = "row";
          Object.keys(jsonInput).forEach(function(k) {
            var string = k;
            var range = jsonInput[k];
            var col4Div = document.createElement("div");
            col4Div.className = "col-md-4 icon-plus";
            var alcohol = document.createElement("span");
            alcohol.className = string;
            var strong = document.createElement("strong");
            strong.innerHTML = string;
            var dropDownArrow = document.createElement("span");
            dropDownArrow.className = "down-arrow";
            alcohol.innerHTML = strong;
            alcohol.innerHTML = dropDownArrow;
            alcohol.innerHTML = "<br/>";
            alcohol.innerHTML = range;
            col4Div.innerHTML = alcohol;
            row.innerHTML = col4Div;
          });
          colDiv.innerHTML=row;
        }
```

when I click the button, it gives me message as `[object HTMLDivElement]` and in console it shows no error.

I'm really confused on what's going on in the backend. My expected output is

```
<div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 icon-plus">
               <span class="a">
               <strong>a</strong>
               <span class="down-arrow"></span>
               <br /> 1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 icon-plus">
               <span class="b">
               <strong>b</strong>
               <span class="down-arrow"></span>
               <br /> 2</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Here is a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/p9e7cLg9/1/

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is going on in the backend, everything is on front end. If JSON was received with success, that's it, backend has done it's job, so you don't have to focus your debugging towards there for sure. And your mock fails, meaning problem is in it.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith, I'm getting the exact JSON from backend

Comment: I am not sure even how output should look like, your transform code is a mess, mixing DOM nodes with text (strings). But it shoudl go along the lines of: var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` deals in **strings** (of HTML source code). `createElement` deals in **DOM nodes**.

When you convert a DOM node to a string, you get `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`, which isn't useful, so don't do that.

Use [the `appendChild` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add a DOM node as a child of an existing HTML element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip. but a small question, here I'm creating divs on the go, for ex. I created div1, then div2 (both using JS), in this case, will `appendChildwork`?

Comment: @user3872094 — Better than just assigning things with `innerHTML` would.